# A verb -- without negative verbs/adverbs -- that means "do/does not"?

Tags: negation

Consider the following sentence:

> Alan does not intend to inform us.

So Alan is saying something and what he is saying is true, but he just does not intend to inform us, that is, he doesn't care to inform us but intends something else. So I tell a friend of mine that it is not Alan't intention to inform us.

Now, what should I do if I want to add an adverb to the verb in the above sentence?

> Alan secretly does not intend to inform us.

So, I now want to tell to the same friend that Alan does not reveal that he does not intend to inform us, that is, he does not reveal his real intention but he somehow let us believe that he just intend to inform us.

The above sentence with the adverb "secretly" seems problematic or ambiguous. Generally, it seems to me that adverbs before "do/does not" are ambiguous or at leas unidiomatic, aren't they? One way out of the problem is to find a verb meaning "does not" which does not have "does not".

Two verbs I have in mind are *fail* and *cease*. But these two verbs seem to add a sense to the negation. *Fail to intend* means *not to be able to intend* or *do not be successful to intend.* [Source](https://www.google.de/search?q=fail%20to%20meaning&rlz=1C1CHZL_enIR733IR733&oq=fail%20to%20meaning&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l4.4595j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) And *cease to intend* means *stop to intend*. [Source](https://www.google.de/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enIR733IR733&q=cease&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwif5oKSosDVAhXMuBoKHe4CCq8QBQgjKAA&biw=1517&bih=735)

The other way out of the problem is to change the sentence into something like:

> Alan secretly lacks the intention of informing us.

But, again, *lack the intention of* has the sense of "be in need of the intention of" or some other related senses. Besides, "secretly lacks" is weird itself.

But I do not want such extra senses. So, I am looking for a verb without "not" to use instead of "do/does not" so that I can put the intended adverb before it.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're after here, but if you're going to stick with the words ***tell the truth***, it's hard to see how you can express his intention (secret or not) without including ***not*** to explicitly negate it. Though some people might prefer *Secretly, he **intends not to** tell the truth* or other variants. But you can also avoid the need for "do-support" by using an antonym of the relevant verb, as in *He secretly intends to **lie**.*

Comment: 'Alan secretly does not intend to tell the truth.' is unambiguous, paraphrasable as 'Alan does not intend to tell the truth, a fact he's keeping secret'. Adverb positioning often disambiguates. Contrast 'Alan does not intend to secretly tell the truth. [He intends to shout it from the rooftops.]'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Do you agree with what I've said about *fail* and *cease*? So, there is nothing wrong with the sentence? Isn't it unidiomatic?
 And, what about parallel sentence "Alan secretly does not have the intention of telling the truth."? Shouldn't I put the adverb after "does"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you think my sentence with "secretly" is unambiguous?

Comment: @Sasan: To be honest, no. But undeniably my first paraphrasing *(Secretly, he intends not to tell the truth)* is "ambiguous", in that it could be interpreted as meaning *I am **telling you in secret** that he intends to lie* (the speaker might think this information is "secret", even if the person being spoken about doesn't know or care about secrecy). But things like this often involve fine or contrived distinctions. In *I secretly intend to lie,* people don't know my ***intention***. But if I openly admit that *I intend to lie secretly* I mean that ***people won't know when I'm lying***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The question is now edited to avoid some misunderstandings.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question is now edited to avoid some misunderstandings.

Comment: How about "Alan intends to lie"?  or "to conceal the truth"?

Comment: @Xanne But he doesn't intend to lie. He just does not intend to tell the truth.

Comment: Too convoluted for me to sort out.  Sorry.

Comment: @Xanne I now edited the question to avoid that misunderstanding.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Too much misunderstandings. So I edited the question again.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Too much misunderstandings. So I edited the question again.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The reason why I think "secretly does not inform" is ambiguous is that it is not clear what the adverb modifies. Does it modify "not informing"? Can "not doing" be modified at all?

Comment: @FumbleFingers The reason why I think "secretly does not inform" is ambiguous is that it is not clear what the adverb modifies. Does it modify "not informing"? Can "not doing" be modified at all?

Comment: 'Alan secretly does not intend to tell the truth.' is unambiguous, paraphrasable as 'Alan does not intend to tell the truth, a fact he's keeping secret'. 'Secretly' in this position means that he his keeping stumm about _**his decision** not to tell the truth_. This answers the question contained in the first 6 paragraphs of your question (after which the question becomes unclear). Ambiguousness is largely concerned with different interpretations, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can use a better understanding, but I am not sure I can find it on ELL. Also, it is not always about our English knowledge. You earlier put "secretly" at the begging of the sentence, which is clearly ambiguous. Sometimes it is about the context. Anyway, I still think that to use adverb to modify "do/does not + verb" is not common or idiomatic. But maybe this general issue should be put into a separate question.

Comment: What is “A verb… without negative verbs…”?

Is “Alan does not intend to inform us” about truth?

Did “in the above sentence” mean “… below…” or what?

Telling a friend it’s not Alan’s intention to inform you means what?

“I want to tell to the same friend” or “I now want to tell/ to say to…”. Which?

In your example sentence what difference did "secretly" make? How was that problematic or ambiguous.

Might it be that if “one way out of the problem is to find a verb meaning ‘does not’ which does not have ‘does not’, that said more about your understanding than about the problem?

Answer (score 1):

These are the negative words which can help us to avoid using"does not" in this particular sentence:

1. He refrains from telling the truth.
2. He avoids telling the truth.

Comment: That is not what I meant. I edited the question.

Comment: Too much misunderstandings. So I edited the question again.

Comment: "He avoids to tell the truth" is not grammatical.

Comment: 'he avoids telling the truth', instead.